# Resources for making an Ubuntu-based router?

Tags: 10.10, networking, virtualization

I need a dead simple (read dumbies) guide to setting an Ubuntu 10.10 machine up as a router.

Here's the scenario:

I have several Ubuntu 10.10 VM's that run on the same virtual network. I want them all to use one of the VM's as a router. That machine will be the only one able to access real network resources and the internet. Problem is, I've never set a router up on a linux box. I'm sure it's very easy but I'd like to get the simple-mans guide if there is one. I'm sure it's out there somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and simplest way is to turn on Internet-connection sharing in the machine you want to use as a router: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1183420&highlight=xbox+360+bridge

For that to work, your router machine would need 2 network interfaces - one connected to the Internet and one connected to the other machines.

Then, the other machines would have to have their connections go through your router, which I'm not really sure how to do using VMs (ethernet cables IRL).  Presumably, your VM software could set up the networking to do that, but you might be able get by by manually setting the gateway in your VMs to be your router.

Answer (score 1):

you can also choose n-computing device to share network as well as system resources...

Comment: Can you expand this to explain how?

Answer (score 0):

Once of the best resources for ICS and firewall that I've come across is firestarter. Once you install it by typing `sudo apt-get install firestarter`, you can just run it from Applications > Internet. It requires almost no manual configuration for regular ICS, but also allows you to have fine-grained control over the firewall.